# Using Sheevaplug as a basic server to run tomcat and Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

I'm probably going to be doing an independent study in College next semester on Java web programming with technologies such as Spring and Hibernate. I'm looking for something that can sit in the corner of my dorm room with out being loud and drawing a lot of power. The machine needs to be able to run a very low traffic tomcat and Mysql server that will allow my professor to see my work with out needing to run a Java app server of his own. I’m considering buying a [Sheevaplug](http://www.marvell.com/products/embedded_processors/developer/kirkwood/sheevaplug.jsp) and upgrading it with an 8 or 16 gig sd card. I would install Tomcat, Mysql, and either Git or Subversion on it. Is this a feasible setup for what would basically be a server that would have a maximum of two users using it?

Comment: While it'd be an interesting experiment, I'd be inclined to target something a little more full-featured (especially the memory) and mainstream.  Going with something like an (x86) Atom-based eeeBox would take out a lot of potential hassles (can you even find a JVM for ARM?).

Comment: the JVM, Tomcat, MySQL, Git and Subversion are all available in the Debian ARM repositories.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running multiple grails applications, eclipse, tomcat, mysql, and a couple other utilities running on a 5 year old windows 2k box with less processor speed, memory & disks space than the plug you link to. I hadn't heard of a plug computer before this post, but based on the specs it sounds like it may be an option given your limited use. While I wouldn't be suggest it for a public facing application. It may be suitable for a limited environment like a home or dorm server for hosting personal applications.

If you do buy one I'd like to know how it goes.

Now I'm considering buying one to try it out myself... ;-)

Comment: I should mention the server I'm using as a host is also not publicly accessible and has a limited userbase of about 10-20 people.

Comment: This forum link shows that Java can be installed - but there are issues... http://plugcomputer.org/plugforum/index.php?topic=161.0

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a reasonable tool for the job.

You may want to consider this advice from the Debian ARM mailing list, concerning JVM speeds on a similar device:

- http://www.nabble.com/Java-%2B-Tomcat-slow-on-TS-109-tt20003260.html#a20015796